# how to segregate values from one column into 2 columns as table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

`Journal_T` - Basically this is the journal table with positive and negative values.
Fields are: `id`, `date`, `ref`, `description`, `amount`, `segment`, `period`, `year`.

I want to display this in two separate columns - `debits` (containing positive values) and `credits` (containing negative values).  Following is the query I am using:

```
$qry = mysql_query("SELECT id, date, ref, description, SUM(amount), 
                           segment, period, year
                      FROM Journal_T 
                  GROUP BY segment, year, period, id") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: By display, do you mean, display to the user?  I would suggest doing this in your code, not in your query.  Keep the query straight forward, and then format your html accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the schema, do it with a `CASE`:

```
SELECT id,
  date,
  ref,
  description,
  CASE WHEN SUM(amount) >= 0 THEN SUM(amount) ELSE NULL END AS positive,
  CASE WHEN SUM(amount) < 0 THEN SUM(amount) ELSE NULL END AS negative,
 ,segment,period,year FROM Journal_T GROUP BY segment,year,period,id
```

Comment: @OMG Ponies That may be.  I'm not certain I understand what the original query was pulling but if this works for the OP...

Comment: @OMG Ponies
@Michael
thanks guys. actually i omitted the description,ref,date fields since they are not needed anymore. it's basically a Trial Balance i want to output so all i need is the Segment,Period,Year,GL_ID,Debits & Credits. The query works fine thanks to you guys

Answer (score 1):

@Michael is right in that this kind of problems is commonly solved with the help of CASE. Yet I think he's got it wrong, and the CASEs should indeed be inside the aggregate functions, like @OMG Ponies has correctly pointed out. Here:

```
SELECT
  id,
  date,
  ref,
  description,
  SUM(CASE WHEN amount > 0 THEN Amount END) AS TotalPositive, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN amount < 0 THEN Amount END) AS TotalNegative, 
  segment,
  period,
  year
FROM Journal_T 
GROUP BY segment, year, period, id
```

On a different point, I don't think that the values of `date`, `ref` and `description` have much sense in the output for this query as long as you do not include them in the GROUP BY list. MySQL does allow you to include them into the SELECT list without aggregating, but the values returned for those columns might be arbitrary and not very much related to the other data retrieved, particularly to the sums.